# Why am i getting an error that states the table doesnt exist when it does?

Tags: python, flask

I have some code where I have built a Flask database, however I am receiving some errors on some flask forms that the table 'dogbreed' does not exist. I am a little confused as to why this is. It is the portion on the form (POST and GET) that I am getting this error. I thought that the Class dogbreed is what classified the table. OperationalError
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: dogbreed Am I wrong?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
import os
from wtforms import SubmitField,StringField, IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
SECRET_KEY=os.urandom(32)
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///test.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=True
app.config['SECRET_KEY']=SECRET_KEY
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate=Migrate(app,db)
import pymysql
import creds 

class dogbreed(db.Model):
    Dog_id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    breed=db.Column(db.String(30))
    height=db.Column(db.Integer())
    furcolor=db.Column(db.String(30))
    eyecolor=db.Column(db.String(30))
    longevity=db.Column(db.Integer())
    charactertraits=db.Column(db.String(30))
    commonhealthproblems=db.Column(db.String(30))
    
class DogForm(FlaskForm):
    breed=StringField("breed",validators=[DataRequired()])
    height=IntegerField("height",validators=[DataRequired()])
    furcolor=StringField('furcolor',validators=[DataRequired()])
    eyecolor=StringField('eyecolor',validators=[DataRequired()])
    longevity=IntegerField('longevity',validators=[DataRequired()])
    charactertraits=StringField('charactertraits',validators=[DataRequired()])
    commonhealthproblems=StringField('commonhealthproblems',validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit=SubmitField("POST")
    

def get_conn():
    conn = pymysql.connect(
        host= creds.host,
        user= creds.user, 
        password = creds.password,
        db=creds.db,
        )
    return conn

def execute_query(query, args=()):
    cur = get_conn().cursor()
    cur.execute(query, args)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return rows

def display_html(rows):
    html = ""
    html += """<table><tr><th>Breed</th><th>FurColor</th><th>EyeColor</th><th>Height</th><th>Longevity</th><th>CharacterTraits</th><th>CommonHealthProblems</th></tr>"""

    for r in rows:
        html += "<tr><td>" + str(r[0]) + "</td><td>" + str(r[1]) + "</td><td>" + str(r[2]) + "</td><td>" + str(r[3]) + "</td><td>" + str(r[4]) +"</td><td>" + str(r[5]) + "</td><td>"+ str(r[6]) + "</td></tr>"
    html += "</table></body>" 
    return html
    
@app.route("/viewdog")
def viewdog():
    rows = execute_query("""SELECT Dog_id, Breed,FurColor,EyeColor,Dog.Height,Health.Longevity,Health.CharacterTraits,Health.CommonHealthProblems
                FROM Dog JOIN Health using (Dog_id) 
                ORDER BY Dog_id """)
    return display_html(rows)
    
from flask import render_template,request,url_for, redirect, flash


@app.route('/')
def index():
    title="index"
    Dog=dogbreed.query.all()
    kwargs={'title':title,
            'dogbreed':dogbreed}
    return render_template("index.html",**kwargs)


@app.route("/adddog", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_dog():
    form=DogForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_post=dogbreed(title=form.title.data,post=form.post.data)
        db.session.add(new_post)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template("Dogsinfo.html",form=form)
    

@app.route("/updatedog", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def update_dog():
    if request.method  == 'POST':
        Dog_id = request.form['dog_id']
    else:
        Dog_id = request.args.get('dog_id')
    d=dogbreed.query.filter_by(Dog_id=Dog_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        d.verified = True
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template("updatedog.html")
    
@app.route("/deletedog", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def delete_dog():
    if request.method  == 'POST':
        Dog_id = request.form['dog_id']
    else:
        Dog_id = request.args.get('dog_id')
    p=dogbreed.query.filter_by(Dog_id=Dog_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        db.session.delete(p)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template("deletedog.html")
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
 
@app.route('/form')
def form():
    return render_template('form.html')
 
@app.route('/uploaddog', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def upload_dog():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
        return "File saved successfully"
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not `dogBreed`? It may be case-sensitive.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: OperationalError
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: dogbreed

Comment: Seems you're missing a `db.create_all()` call. Or do you do that somewhere else in your code?